# Ruby Module Declaration

Tags: ruby

Is there any difference between doing

```
class Bus::Driver
end
```

and

```
module Bus
  class Driver
  end
end
```

If not, which syntax is preferred?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any difference between doing [...]?

The only difference is that in `class Bus::Driver` the `Bus` module **must** be already defined, while the same does not stand for the second.

> Which syntax is preferred?

This is not a constructive question but I personally prefer the second because it states explicitly that `Bus` is a module, while with the first I cannot see at first glance if `Bus` is a module or a class.

Answer (score 3):

This, on its own:

```
class Bus::Driver
end
```

will result in an error `NameError: uninitialized constant Bus`

So at some point you have to declare `class Bus` or `module Bus`. It doesn't have to be the full hierarchy each time though.

I tend to have an early require that sets up the namespaces, then use the more condensed form in the rest of my files. I'm not aware that there is any preferred approach - definitely nothing that you would be criticised for.

Answer (score 1):

First syntax is preferred when you have various classes of a module spread across multiple files in a project; and provided `module` is always defined in `PATH`. Such as, while making a `gem`.

Second is more central, and should be done when details are concerned. `module` doesn't not only include `class`, it includes `methods` and `constants` etc for namespace too; which are useful.

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional difference between those declarations when inheritance is involved:

Let's assume `Driver` inherits from a `Person` class.

```
class Bus::Driver < Person
end
```

```
module Bus
  class Driver < Person
  end
end
```

When Ruby tries to resolve the `Person` constant, in the first declaration it only looks for `::Person`. The second one looks for both `Bus::Person` and `::Person`.

Depending on your circumstances this could make one declaration preferrable to the other.